# What does a square-bracketed index after an NSArray mean?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, indexing, nsarray, objective-c-literals

Going through iTunes U Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad and in Lecture 3 slides, on page 120, there's a Quiz question that asks what the following line of code does. Frankly, I'm a bit stumped, and hoped someone could break it down.

```
cardA.contents = @[cardB.contents,cardC.contents][[cardB match:@[cardC]] ? 1 : 0];
```

So, I get the first part, `cardA.contents =` a new array with `cardB.contents` and `cardC.contents` in the array. But, next comes (I guess??) an index that returns either 1 or 0 depending if `cardB` matches an array that includes `cardC`.

Here's what I don't "get", and maybe it's just a syntax issue.... is what this does?

How is

```
cardA.contents = @[cardB.contents,cardC.contents][0];
```

or

```
cardA.contents = @[cardB.contents,cardC.contents][1];
```

Valid? Or, did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is completely correct; you're just missing one bit of syntax. Subscripted access of `NSArray`s with [the `array[index]` form is part of the "collection literals"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#array-style-subscripting) feature introduced by Clang a little while back.

It's transformed by the compiler into a call to `[array objectAtIndexedSubscript:index]`.

Comment: Sure thing. Added a link to the documentation if you're curious, @DrDavid.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, in writing this out, it makes sense. It's literally saying, that if cardB matched cardC, use an index of [1] (cardC), if not, use an index of [0] (cardB)

So,

```
cardA.contents = cardB.contents // if does NOT match
cardA.contents = cardC.contents // if matches
```

(based on the index).

Duh.. Sorry for a silly question...

Comment: Not a silly question, I was initially confused by the syntax of the two brackets as well. Then I realized it was an index next to an array:

Hence cardA.contents will always be equal to the value of cardB.contents